# I have a panel dataset with multiple observations per year, how do I compute the sum of my obs per year without summing the "Year" variable?

Tags: r, frequency, panel-data

I have a panel dataset on disasters per year in one country, with data on GDP per year and casualties and damages in $.
For each observation I have the Year and the CPI,that are the same between two observations of the same year and casualties and costs that are observation-specific.

I'd like to modify my dataset so that I have one line per year with the total costs and casualties per year. I cannot simply compute the sum of all obs that have the same year because that would also sum variables such as CPI that is constant across observations of the same year. How can I do this ?

Here are the first 8 rows of my dataset

```
structure(list(Year = c("1980", "1980", "1980", "1980", "1980", 
"1980", "1980", "1980"), Country.Code = c("PHL", "PHL", "PHL", 
"PHL", "PHL", "PHL", "PHL", "PHL"), duration = structure(c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), class = "difftime", units = "days"), `Total Deaths` = c(50, 
2, 31, 40, 101, 4, NA, 36), `Total Affected` = c(NA, 25980, 6e+05, 
190000, 1004000, 665, 3063, 69237), `Total Damages ('000 US$)` = c(NA, 
NA, 15400, NA, 102300, 402, 289, NA), CPI = c(32.2338932328122, 
32.2338932328122, 32.2338932328122, 32.2338932328122, 32.2338932328122, 
32.2338932328122, 32.2338932328122, 32.2338932328122)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have 500+ rows in total with year up to 2019

What I would like is one line per year, with Country.Code and CPI unchanged but duration, death, affected and damages summed per year.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621058/r-markdown-transforming-pooled-cross-section-data-into-a-panel-data-set) thread and tried to adapt it to my case by doing this

```
disaster %>%
  group_by(Year, Country.Code,CPI) %>%
  summarise(
    sum_duration = sum(duration),
    sum_total_deaths = sum(`Total Deaths`),
    sum_total_affected=sum(`Total Affected`),
    sum_total_damages=sum(`Total Damages ('000 US$)`)
  )
```

Using the dyplyr package, where disaster is my dataset, Year, Country.Code and CPI are the variables that I do not want to sum, duration is the cumulated length of all disasters per year, measured in days, and all others are self-explanatory.

This does not work.

In case you're wondering what I'll do with this, I will merge this with data on GDP and do some time-series analysis but I already know how to do this.

Any help appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or `dput` a sample of your data.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Doe sit give error or an incorrect result. You can add `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum` to ignore `NA` values.

Comment: My issue is that I now have an error message : 
Error in disaster %>% group_by(Year, Country.Code, CPI) %>% summarise(sum_duration = sum(duration),  :  impossible to find function "%>%"

Comment: Did you load the library `dplyr` with `library(dplyr)` ?

Comment: I was sure I ran the entire code again with libraries and all but apparently I didn't. Thank you so much !

Comment: I do not know why but the code doesn't work anymore. I sent it to someone else and the code gave back only one observation of the 4 variables I wanted to sum; it computed the sum across all years and did not keep year, CPI or country code (which I need for future merging). I restarted the file, ran everything from start to finish and got the same as them. Does anyone have any idea as to why that happened ?